# Getting started to Rails app testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I want you guys to tell em the best options when it comes to testing Rails code. In special testing Mongoid models and standard controllers, thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "best options"? in general, it's a good idea to have a look at the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meet your new best friends:

[RSpec](http://rspec.info/)

[FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/)

[Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/)

[Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/) and [Spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork)

See this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

Answer (score 1):

For mongoid

https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec

Answer (score 0):

I really like this blog article series. It goes step by step, shows what you can test in different contexts (Model, Controller, Integration) and just provides a great overview.

http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html